# How do I remove a texture node from my animation after using it

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor

I am making an animation by using keyframes on the node sliders, for example i used a noise texture node and the scale goes from over 100 down to zero. I want to stop having the noise affect my texture after the frame where it gets to 0 and start using other ones, but if i remove or disconnect the noise it removes it from the whole animation. How can i get the noise to stop affecting it while letting it work for the first few frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove texture node.
Add **Mix RGB** node and animate *Factor* from 0 to 1 affect appearance of second texture node.

[image]
For some reason, captured gif didnt recorded Factor value, but it is there :)

Comment: awesome, thanks :D